# entity manager remove functions works slowly

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

I am trying to delete a record from the database using the `EntityManager.remove` function, it works fine. But it takes time to delete. I have to click on the button many times to make it work, sometimes I wait for some time and then click on delete and it might work. 
Following is my code

```
@Override
    public void delete(int divID) {

        IncentiveEntity a = em.find(IncentiveEntity.class, new Integer(divID));
            em.remove(a);
       em.flush();      

    }
```

Comment: Your code does 2 things: It first loads the entity (which might cause the delay) and then it deletes it. As a first step, I suggest you use `IncentiveEntity a = entityManager.getReference(divId)` and then `remove` it. This way, you can avoid the DB fetch. If the performance issue persists, please include the entity class and/or DB schema for the entity (including foreign keys and indexes).

Comment: @Cascader Thank you for the answer, but with this query line it won't even delete it now